# Function in Oracle SQL where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees emp 
WHERE emp.loc = 'US' 
  AND usr.fnctn('emp_sal', :sal1, :sal2);
```

This query causes an error:

> ORA-00920: invalid RELATIONAL OPERATOR

My function just returns the highest and the lowest sal in `employees` table

Comment: Where is your question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm very sorry sir. Just edited it.

Comment: You can not use boolean inside of sql, so `fnctn` must return something else and therefore you need some relation to compare the return value with.

Comment: Your function returns two values? Not possible except it returns collection.

Comment: yes sir. I forgot to mention it. it returns values like for example 500,700

Comment: "https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/parameter_declaration.htm#CJADCJFE" - "Avoid using OUT and IN OUT with functions. The purpose of a function is to take zero or more parameters and return a single value. Functions must be free from side effects, which change the values of variables not local to the subprogram."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function returns a value.

In the where clause you need to compare that return value with something, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees emp 
WHERE emp.loc = 'US' 
AND usr.fnctn('emp_sal', :sal1, :sal2) = 42;
```